# Store doubles in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I really need help to store double values in a double array. I am trying using scanf_s and it works. But if I try to input more than 4 values, my program crashes and returns me the error code 3

I actually need a dynamic array, but as I was getting too many errors with that, I changed and I'm trying to use a common array, just so I can get at least some marks for this project.

This is the code I am using now...

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter white-space separated real numbers. Terminate input with ^Z\n");
    //get the dynamic array

    double numSet[1000] = { 0 };
    int size = 0;
    double number;
    while (scanf_s("%lf", &number) == 1)
    {
        numSet[size] = number;
        size++;
    }


    //sort the array using qsort 


    //range of the array 

    double min = numSet[0];
    double max = numSet[size - 1];


    //get the mean 
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += numSet[i];
    }

    double mean = sum / size;



    printf("Range: [%.2f ... %.2f]\n", min, max);
    printf("Arithmetic mean is: %f", mean);



}
```

I have two problems:

1. Is a warning about buffer overrun:

   ```
   Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'numSet':
   the readable size is '8000' bytes, but '-8' bytes may be read.
   ```
2. When I try to input more than 4 numbers, my program crashes and returns the code 3

Comment: Are you sure that size>0 when you do double max = numSet[size - 1]; ? Or more generally, is this all the code? How do you do qsort?

Comment: Note that if run on Unix, hitting `^Z` (control-Z) will put your program into suspended animation and let the shell take control again — without actually terminating the program.  On Windows, typing `^Z` indicates EOF.

Comment: You don't check that `size` is at least `1` before referencing the (possibly non-existent) data in the array. That's the warning from the compiler. —— I see you've removed a section of code `sort the array using qsort`.  Does the code you show crash, or only the code you don't show? (Sorting is not necessarily wrong, but isn't needed to get `min` and `max`.)

Comment: Are you required to use an array at all? If an array is not required your program is far more complicated than necessary. Your input loop can simply accumulate a total for all input values, count the number of input values, and identify the minimum and maximum values input.

Comment: The only errors I see are 1) a possibile buffer overrun (which you've acknowledged in stating that you need a dynamic array) that could be "fixed" by changing your loop condition to: `while(size < 1000 && scanf_s("%lf", &number) == 1)`, and 2) various bugs when `size` is 0 such as a) invalid array access at index -1, as the compiler is warning you, and b) division by 0.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need only the mean. I need to perform lots of statistics so I can not use a loop only to perform the sum...

Answer (score 3):

```
while (scanf_s("%lf", &number) == 1)
    {
        numSet[size] = number;
        size++;
    }
```

instead of this use

```
while (scanf_s("%lf", &number) == 1 && size <= 1000)
    {
        numSet[size] = number;
        size++;
    }
```

Your loop goes infinitely because it has no termination character.
`scanf_s` only reads value from keyboard and has another parameter to set its maximum input buffer value which is useful to limit your input.

What you can do is either read size from the user before letting him enter values or you can ask every time if the user wants to add more values to the array or not.

for example:

```
char option = 'Y';
while ( (scanf_s("%lf", &number) == 1 && option == 'Y'){
   // code to enter a new number
   printf("Do you want to add more numbers? (Y/N) ");
   scanf("%c", &option);
}
```

Also, the `scanf_s` function returns the number of values scanned and every time is 1 as you are always taking one double value.

So even if you remove it, it wont be of much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's possible for

```
double max = numSet[size - 1];
```

to evaluate as

```c
double max = numSet[-1];
```

when `size = 0`. I'm guessing that a `double` is 8 bytes wide, so the compiler warns that it could try to read `-1 * 8 = -8` bytes from memory.

Comment: Looking at the MS manual page for [`scanf_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) suggests that your "extra argument" idea is wrong for `double` (it shows an example of `float` being used without the extra argument, and the commentary says that the lengths are required for string-related conversion specifiers — not for numeric ones.  'Tis funny, because we're linking to almost the same URL, but coming to opposite conclusions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you seem to have read the documentation more closely than I. It says "Specify the sizes for all c, C, s, S, or string control set [] parameters" with no mention of numeric types, as you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you end the input loop, scanf_s isn't needed, please see the watch window. I simply change the end condition to some no digit char.

Code::Blocks watch window

[image]